# How to make packages using cli commands?

Tags: python, terminal, pip

I tried using `bitmex-market-maker` python package.

[Here](https://github.com/BitMEX/sample-market-maker)'s how to use this package.

> Install: `pip install bitmex-market-maker`. It is strongly recommeded to use a virtualenv.
>
> Create a marketmaker project: run `marketmaker setup`

I learned how to make my own command-line commands using python [here](https://dbader.org/blog/how-to-make-command-line-commands-with-python).

To make my own commands, however, I had to type several terminal commands like

> $ chmod +x marketmaker.py
>
> $ mv marketmaker.py marketmaker
>
> $ mkdir -p ~/bin
>
> $ cp marketmaker ~/bin
>
> $ export PATH=$PATH":$HOME/bin"

But I didn't type this commands at all but only installed `bitmex-market-maker` package using pip.

Can you help me figuring out how things work behind the scene?

I post marketmaker codes.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from market_maker import market_maker
market_maker.run()
```

Comment: When you install the package with a virtualenv enabled, there will be a folder in your directory `{virtualenv name}/bin/`. This is where your shell commands for that environment are installed. Without a virtualenv enabled when you install the package, the command will be placed in :$HOME/bin

Comment: you can always put these command in file - ie. `script` - and run it with bash  - `bash script` - or create executable bash script - similar like you created python executable script but with different shebang - `#!/bin/sh`. You can also run commands from python script using `os.system("command arg1 arg2")` or `subprocess.run(["command", "arg1", "arg2"])`. And you don't have to create package for this.

Comment: btw: you can put `export` in `.bashrc` and it will set it everytime when you login to your computer. Folder `~/bin` you already created so you will no have to do it again. So to create another executable you will have to only move it to `~/bin` and use `chmod` - so there is no need to create special script for this.